# Add content to a custom tab in WooCommerce admin single product data options settings

Tags: php, woocommerce, backend, product, hook-woocommerce

I created a custom tab on the product data options panel, but i don't know how to write the content on it. I have yet a code that prints the options (checkboxes, texts etc) that was on the inventory tab using the hook `add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku','add_leadlovers_custom_fields' );`

I used this code to generates [this tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2hCu.png).

```
function adicionar_guia_leadlovers($tabs) {
    $tabs['guia_leadlovers'] = array(
        'label'    => __( 'LeadLovers', 'text-domain' ),
        'target'   => 'leadlovers_product_data',
        'class'    => array( 'show_if_simple', 'show_if_variable' ),
    );
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'adicionar_guia_leadlovers' );
```

But, what hook can I use to replace 'woocommerce_product_options_sku' and wrtite the options on my own custom tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the missing hooked function, to display the content (and save field values) for your additional product settings tab "**LeadLovers**":

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'add_leadlovers_guide_product_tab' );
function add_leadlovers_guide_product_tab($tabs) {
    $tabs['leadlovers_guide'] = array(
        'label'    => __( 'LeadLovers', 'text-domain' ),
        'target'   => 'leadlovers_product_data',
        'class'    => array( 'show_if_simple', 'show_if_variable' ),
    );
    return $tabs;
}

// Display the content
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'display_readlovers_guide_product_data_tab_content' );
function display_readlovers_guide_product_data_tab_content() {
    global $product_object;

    echo '<div id="leadlovers_product_data" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">
    <div class="options_group">';

    ## ---- Content Start ---- ##

    echo '<p>This is your LeadLovers content for the product "<strong>'.$product_object->get_name().'</strong>"…</p>';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'          => '_leadlovers',
        'value'       => $product_object->get_meta('_leadlovers'),
        'label'       => __('LeadLovers field', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => '',
        'description' => __('LeadLovers description text.', 'woocommerce'),
    ));

    ## ---- Content End  ---- ##

    echo '</div></div>';
}

// Save field values
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_leadlovers_guide_fields_values' );
function save_leadlovers_guide_fields_values( $product ) {
    $leadlovers = isset( $_POST['_leadlovers'] ) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['_leadlovers']) : '';
    $product->update_meta_data( '_leadlovers', $leadlovers );
}
```

Then you will get:

[image]

Comment: very thanks @Loic... I was found this hook, but didn't understand the problem was the id and class of the div... thanks!